# How can I do a separated sector of doughnut diagram with Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

can you help me? I have to do a doughnut diagram and I don't know how to make the violet sector [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/ldidyp)

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 3', 'Company 4'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First Dataset',
        data: [6900, 3450, 2300, 1800],
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: [
          '#7976FF',
          '#FFB546',
          '#FE6779',
          '#F4F5F7'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: false,
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8s2grvn/)

Comment: I'm confused with what you're asking can you clarify?

Comment: You want to highlight the sector when you hover ?